# Why "No paper can bear more than $7$ times"

Tags: logic, soft-question

Today in the math lesson, the teacher told us: "No paper can bear more than $7$ times". But, did not say why.. Is there a mathematical reason here?

Comment: Relevant? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britney_Gallivan

Comment: [Mythbusters tackled this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRAEBbotuIE)

Comment: @JMoravutz Thank you.. Amazing!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but not with a regular piece of paper (A4 or letter size, for instance). After folding it seven times, if your folding is perfect, you now have $128$ layers on top of one another. Folding a stack of $128$ papers is difficult even when the papers are full-size.

Also, the paper has some thickness to is, which makes the creases behave badly. For instance, the last fold takes you from $64$ layers to $128$ layers. The distance that the outermost piece of paper has to cover to reach around that fold is about $200$ times the thickness of the paper, so the top and bottom layers become much smaller than the middle layers. Also, the curving of all these pieces of paper  around the fold makes the folds very resistant to bending.

Combined with the fact that the average amount of paper per layer (and thus more or less the surface area of the stack itself) is $1/128$th of the original size of the paper, there just isn't any paper left to fold.

Comment: Wow, It is possible for $8$ times? With Special paper

Comment: @Newstudent There is a link in the comments above where they do 11, but that's _really_ special paper, and a lot of work. I guess you've seen that by now, though.

Comment: Yes..I saw now..